# Public functors using anonymous classes

Tags: c++, function, anonymous-class

I have a pure virtual class `CF` that denotes any continuous function in 1D it is defined a header file

```
// tools.h
class CF
{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double x) const=0 ;
};
```

what I intend to do is to wrap a couple of simple functions using functors and have them defined inside `tools.h`. If I use anonymous classes, like:

```
// tools.h
class : public CF{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double x) const { return 0.0; }
} zero;
```

then I run into trouble sine the class is redefined everywhere `tools.h` is included. gcc complains:

```
// tools.h included in main.cpp, foo.cpp, and bar.cpp
foo.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `zero'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
bar.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `zero'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

I figured I could fix this by doing something like:

```
// tools.h
class zero_: public CF{
public:
    virtual double operator()(double x) const { return 0.0; }
};

const static zero_ zero;
```

but I don't like it since `zero_` is visible everywhere and I don't need it to be! How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not doing it. Just have

```
struct zero : public CF {
  double operator()(double x) { return 0.; }
};
```

And use it with

```
void fun(const CF& cf);
fun(zero());
```

One of the reasons to have functors over functions is their ability to carry and expose state through operations, your approach would throw that away for gaining 2 parenthesis in conciseness.

Comment: Well for simple functors, like `zero`, I wont need any extra information to be passed around. The reason behind using functors in this case, rather than normal functions, is that rest of the code is written using the `CF` base class.

Comment: @GradGuy I said: One of the reasons. There are a few more like automatic argument deduction for templates, automatic overload disambiguation, or here run-time polymorphism. All things you don't get with functions. What your are trying to do is just heavily against what the language is intended to do and such situations are really rare in C++ because it can do nearly everything.

Comment: I think you are correct; it's better to stick with standards. Thanks